# Get Storyboard from Dependency property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

Can i get a Storyboard that is currently changing my DP in static OnChange event of that DP ?

Any solution (WPF,SL, SL for WP7) would be great

Comment: Do you want to know the currently running storyboards on your Dependency Property?

Comment: Meleak - exactly. Sorry for misleading question. Changed the question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

The long answer is: still no.  Its a bit like having all methods carry an extra object parameter that would get assigned `this` whenever a call is made.  The overhead would be unbearable.